# Find domains using one tag?

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

I have domain names with `tags` in table1

`tags` are sperated by commas. example

```
domain        tags
facebook.com  facebook,social,networking,friends,community
```

I want to search domains by one tag, say "social" so how do I do it?
I was using this query for multi tags but it doesnt work for single.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('social')
```

I have enabled FULL TEXT SEARCH in table1

How do I query with single tag and get info about domains related to `social`

Comment: When you said "related", do you mean "has the [social] tag", or "match synonyms of 'social'"?

Answer (score 0):

this should help you:

```
select * from table1 where tags like '%social%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, a `LIKE` query will probably get you what you want, but bear in mind that all of these examples would match both the `social` tag and any tag that has the phrase "social" in it (for instance, if you had a tag like `social-networking` or `ice-cream-social`, it would match all of these).

You *really* should normalize this table structure. Eliminate your `tags` column and introduce another table. Something like `DomainTag`.

```
DomainTag
-------------
DomainId
TagId
```

A domain having multiple tags would result in multiple rows in `DomainTag`. To find a domain with a given tag, you do a query against `DomainTag`, either joining to `Domain` if `DomainId` is something other than `domain`, or just returning the domain name directly.

Comment: nice article :P heheh i aggre with you but however he asked for all wich are related to social and **social-networking** & **ice-cream-social** are related to it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

***Note:** Others have suggested LIKE but it is not optimized for fulltext queries, since it will scan the entire table.*

You might want to look at the manual for [MATCH.. AGAINST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) and see if you are missing anything.  e.g.

- If 50% of your rows contain the tag social, then it won't be in the index at all (too common)

But the real issue is most likely that you should be specifying the mode

```
SELECT * FROM dom2 WHERE MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('social' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: I miss the mode oh I was using it but forgot for this query and that leads all confusion thabnks any way.

Comment: @leon - No worries. If the problem is solved you can tick this as the answer - cheers!

Comment: I have found a limitations for this means if your tag number is less that 4 or say 3 then it wont search...for example 'SEO' tag

Comment: tag number means number of letters tag contain

Comment: well I found a solution you need to edit my.cnf [mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3

Comment: but apart from do you have any other options??

Comment: Full text searches are not for very small words, such as "a", "in", "or", "the"... these are almost pointless and make the index almost useless. If you do need them at any time (rarely), you will have to resort to LIKE using table scan.